# Opensearchserver how to crawl pdf content in a database

Tags: database, pdf, web-crawler

I have a bunch of pdf documents but all the document data are in a database (file name, description, id of the client, and the complete pdf content as a field of the data base).
Is possible to relate the pdf parser to take the data from a field of a database crawler?

thanks